# why try catch block faster than normal in NodeJS v7

Tags: javascript, node.js

```
function f(){
    let n = 0
    console.time('f')

    for (let i = 0; i < 1000000000; i++) {
        n += 1
    }

    console.timeEnd('f')
}

function g(){
    let n = 0
    console.time('g')

    try {
        for (let i = 0; i < 1000000000; i++) {
            try {
                n += 1
            }catch(e) {}
        }
    }catch(e){}

    console.timeEnd('g')
}
f();g();
```

output result

```
➜  static node -v
v7.9.0
➜  static node test.js
f: 11293.079ms
g: 5800.848ms
➜  static sudo n 6.9.5
➜  static node -v
v6.9.5
➜  static node test.js
f: 9922.718ms
g: 12212.024ms
➜  static
```

why try catch block faster than normal 2x

is that means we should work with all try?

try everything to get more performance

hope to get the answer

thankx all

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The version of V8 in node v7.x allows functions containing try-catch or try-finally blocks to be optimized, whereas previously they were *always* permanently deoptimized. However, Crankshaft still cannot inline functions with try-catch or try-finally. This may change with TurboFan (+ Ignition) though.

Comment: means that i can try everything to got optimized?

Comment: That does answer only a part of the question. According to OP, it seems that code without try/catch constructs is executed slower, compared to when it is wrapped in try/catch.

Comment: Using try-catch or try-finally doesn't *cause* an optimization to occur. It's that in previous versions of V8, functions containing those blocks were *never* optimized by the V8 compiler/optimizer. Now with the version of V8 in node v7.x, the compiler/optimizer *can* and *will* optimize functions containing such blocks.

Comment: is there any document about this?

Comment: As to why the try-catch-containing function appears to be faster than the one without it, that would require some investigation by turning on appropriate V8 flags (e.g. `--trace-opt --trace-deopt`) to show what is happening. Many times it's best to run benchmarks separately, in case the V8 optimizer affects other parts of the code (outside of a particular function).

Comment: Also when benchmarking, it's important to make sure that the results are statistically significant and not just different due to noise introduced from various places.

Answer (score 0):

looks like a sub-optimal `let i` handling.
With the current versions of node, it's still safer to avoid `let`
unless one really really needs the scoping.

When I run the above unmodified:

```
% node-v7.8.0 t.js
f: 6069.986ms
g: 3926.725ms
```

Changing `let i` to `var i` above the loop the optimized version without try is now faster, and note the huge speedup for both with-try and without-try:

```
% node-v7.8.0 t.js
f: 2349.275ms
g: 2998.101ms
```

The modified source:

```
function f(){
    let n = 0
    console.time('f')
    var i;

    for (i = 0; i < 1000000000; i++) {
    n += 1
    }

    console.timeEnd('f')
}

function g(){
    let n = 0
    console.time('g')
    var i;

    try {
        for (i = 0; i < 1000000000; i++) {
            try {
                n += 1
            }catch(e) {}
    }
    }catch(e){}

    console.timeEnd('g')
}
f();g();
```